# Error "Vars in a Task must be specified as a dictionary, or a list of dictionaries"

Tags: dictionary, variables, ansible, undefined

'data_list' consists of the values in the csv file. I want to use the values in 'data_list' to loop through the parameters in the 'Create user' section of the playbook, but I am getting this error after running my playbook:

```
TASK [Create Multiple Users : Create multiple users] ***************************
fatal: [10.16.220.30]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Vars in a Task must be specified as a dictionary, or a list of dictionaries\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/Windows AD/roles/Create Multiple Users/tasks/Create_multiple_users.yml': line 14, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      - \"{{ item.groups }}\"\n  vars: data_list\n        ^ here\n"}
```

This is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Read Users 
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    data_list: []
  tasks:
  - read_csv:
      path: user.csv
      key: name  
      fieldnames: name,firstname,surname,displayName,groups
      delimiter: ','
    register: userdata


  - name: Extract the list
    set_fact:
      data_list: "{{ data_list + [{ 'name': item.value.name, 'firstname': item.value.firstname, 'surname': item.value.surname, 'displayName': item.value.displayName, 'groups': item.value.groups }] }}"
    loop: "{{ userdata.dict|dict2items }}"


- name: Create user accounts
  hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
  gather_facts: false
  any_errors_fatal: false
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: admin
  roles:
    - { role: Create Multiple Users }


- name: Create users
  community.windows.win_domain_user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    firstname: "{{ item.firstname }}"
    surname: "{{ item.surname }}"
    attributes:
      displayName: "{{ item.firstname + ' ' + item.surname }}"
    groups:
      - "{{ item.groups }}"
  vars: data_list 
  with_items: 
    - "{{ data_list }}"
```

What is the correct vars that I should write?

Comment: Remove the `vars: data_list` line in your last task and replace the looping instruction: `with_items: "{{ hostvars.localhost.data_list }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line causing the error in your task

> ```yaml
>     vars: data_list
> ```

As mentioned in your error message, the `vars` section should look like:

```yaml
    vars:
      var1: value1
      var2: value2
```

But this is not the only problem in you above script. You are gathering your csv data in a separate play on `localhost` and setting that info as a fact in variable `data_list`. When your first play is over, that var will only be known from the `localhost` target. If you want to reuse it in a second play targeting other hosts, you'll have to get that var from the `hostvars` [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

```yaml
{{ hostvars.localhost.data_list }}
```

This is not the best approach here as you can easily shorten your playbook to a single play. The trick here is to delegate your csv gathering task to localhost and set `run_once: true` so that the registered var is calculated only once and distributed to all hosts with the same value. You can also drop the set fact which basically copies the same `key: value` to a new var.

Here is an (untested) example playbook to show you the way:

```yaml
---
- name: Create multiple Windows AD user accounts from CSV
  hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: read csv from localhost (single run same registered var for all hosts)
      read_csv:
        path: user.csv
        key: name  
        fieldnames: name,firstname,surname,displayName,groups
        delimiter: ','
      register: userdata
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Create users
      community.windows.win_domain_user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        firstname: "{{ item.firstname }}"
        surname: "{{ item.surname }}"
        attributes:
          displayName: "{{ item.firstname + ' ' + item.surname }}"
        groups:
          - "{{ item.groups }}"
      # This will work on any number of hosts as `userdata`
      # now has the same value for each hosts inside this play.
      # we just have to extract the values from each keys from
      # `userdata` and loop on that list
      loop: "{{ userdata.dict | dict2items | map(attribute='value') }}"
```

Comment: I definitely haven't heard of magic variables before. Thanks for telling me about it.

"The trick here is to delegate your csv gathering task to localhost and set run_once: true so that the registered var is calculated only once and distributed to all hosts with the same value." What is the registered var? I didn't see any registered var in your example

Comment: I tested your suggestion and the example playbook. The "Create user" task has a failed section: ""msg": "argument for 'groups' is of type System.String and we were unable to convert to bool: The value 'groups' is not a valid boolean. Valid booleans include: y, yes, on, 1, true, t, 1.0, n, no, off, 0, false, f, 0.0"}." The data to be looped into item.groups is 'yes'. It is correct and there is no need for ansible to convert it to bool. How do I make ansible ignore this issue?

Comment: My suggestions both fix the way you declare and use your vars. It will not fix incorrect data in your CSV which we have absolutely no idea about nor a wrong usage of your module which I cannot test without a windows machine available. Please read [mre] and edit your question with the needed information if you need further assistance. Meanwhile, debugging `userdata.dict` and reading the win_domain_user module documentation should be enough to find your current problem.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the explanations and suggestions!